# Unknown error code in heroku "One or more of these arguments were missing"

Tags: python-3.x, heroku

**Clarification of the question:**

A python app suddenly fails to start on Heroku. There were no changes to the app, but a previously unseen error prevents the app from starting:

> One or more of these arguments were missing: uid, gid, gateway,
> somaxconn, event_fd, out_fd

Since no changes were deployed and restarts don't help it's safe to assume that something changed on Heroku side.

**Original post:**

My application crashed and I am experiencing problems restarting it. I am getting the same error code every time: One or more of these arguments were missing: uid, gid, gateway, somaxconn, event_fd, out_fd. I do not understand the meaning of this error code along with its origin. Can you please help?

I tried to restart and redeploy the application.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I  encountered the same error today on an app that was working fine for years. No updates were done to the app it just stopped working.

Comment: I currently have the same issue, have raised a support ticket.How did you resolve your issue @MikhailBeliansky (if you have that is)

Comment: @Richlewis I can't even understand the problem yet. So far I'm setting up an EC2 server to run the app from. Heroku is just a pile of disappointment any way.

Comment: I know the issue, if you are running a basic dyno then Heroku are having problems, if you temporarily upgrade to the standard 1x/2x type it will fix the issue straight away (you can always change it back once Heroku have fixed their end) @MikhailBeliansky

Comment: @d3kxrma See above for a temp solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote to heroku support and they have already fixed this bug. Here is the link: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2584

Answer (score 1):

Seems heroku was down for a bit. I believe it should now be working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).